# How to visualize heatmap for thousands of records

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, heatmap

I have a thousands of records (lat,lng) on my java appengine and I'd like to generate a heatmap for it using [Android Heatmap Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap). However the raw data set is too big to be transferred via mobile network. How do you preprocess those records into something small enough so it can be transferred to the device?

Comment: Have you tried compression on your (json/csv file)?

Comment: compression doesn't help in this case. Sure it will be smaller but the data set is still too large. There must be a way how to prepare the data on the server so I don't have to fetch every single record on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the LatLngs in one (or multiple) JSON files with the format stated in the docs you mentioned.

```
[
{"lat" : -37.1886, "lng" : 145.708 } ,
{"lat" : -37.8361, "lng" : 144.845 } ,
{"lat" : -38.4034, "lng" : 144.192 } ,
{"lat" : -38.7597, "lng" : 143.67 } ,
{"lat" : -36.9672, "lng" : 141.083 }
]
```

Then retrieve them in your app using an AsyncTask and update your HeatMap calling the `.setData(data);` method on your `HeatmapTileProvider`

EDIT:

A possible solution:

Create a "grid" over your theoretic map of whatever size you seem fit, then average the position of all markers that fit inside every cell on the grid, and assign that new marker a weight of how many markers were originally in the grid.
Then you can use`WeightedLatLng` and `.weightedData` on your HeatMap instead of the regular `LatLng` and `.data`.

Smaller "grids" should yield more accurate results, but again, it depends on the size of your data.

Comment: The point is, the data set is too large to send every single record to the device. I was thinking about some averaging however I'm not sure what is the best way to average a set of coordinates.

Comment: Additionally you can use the zoom level to vary the set of WeightedLatLng you are pulling from the server. This in combination with setRadius() will allow you handle zooming in/out of the map.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using all the **data-sets**, you can use **sample data sets** for your app, which will give **reliable result**.

### Use sampling Algorithm:

**Run Sampling Algorithm** in your server which will reduce the large data size into very small. [Spatial sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_analysis) involves determining a limited number of locations in geographic space for faithfully measuring phenomena that are subject to dependency and heterogeneity.

---

### Shuffling:

**Shuffling** is the process of rearranging an array of elements randomly. For example, you might shuffle a deck of cards before dealing a poker game. A good shuffling algorithm is unbiased, where every ordering is equally likely.

> The Fisher–Yates shuffle is an optimal shuffling algorithm. Not only
>   is it unbiased, but it runs in linear time, uses constant space, and
>   is easy to implement.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var n = array.length, t, i;
  while (n) {
    i = Math.random() * n-- | 0; // 0 ≤ i < n
    t = array[n];
    array[n] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}
```

For detail information: [Visualizing Algorithms](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/)